# How to get autocomplete data shared for all rows and columns across entire spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, autocomplete, autofill

I have a Google spreadsheet and autocomplete is only working for the columns I am typing in, meaning if there is `word1` in the column I am typing in, and I start to type a word, it will suggest `word1`, but WILL NEVER suggest `word5` from the column next door. I am trying to make autocomplete data shared for all columns and rows.

**Example 1-a:**
[image: Example 1-a:]

**Example 1-b:**
[image: Example 1-b:]

See what I mean? I'd like for autocomplete to suggest the word `WORRY` but it won't. I am trying to share autocomplete data across the entire spreadsheet rather than just to individual column data.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, that is not possible to achieve. autocomplete is available only in few cases when in the same column. best you can do is to use Data Validation on the whole sheet (selection) with disabled dropdown menu (for visual) but this can have undesired result in the form of a red arrow in the top right corner of the cell.

Comment: How can this not be possible? It is such a simple request of implementation, so simple!

Comment: Just because things seem simple does not mean they are in implementation!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer since this is, from what I hear...not possible.

***The linux program ... "TextSuggest".***

Easily download and install TextSuggest from the AUR repo.

```
yay -S textsuggest
```

It will do exactly as Google Sheets autocomplete feature does, but within your entire Linux system.

[image]

> If you wish to see/learn more, here is a nice article/review on it.
>
> https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/quick-text-autocomplete-desktop-linux

TextSuggest is the best alternative to the "not possible".